# How to subtract a value from an array in node-js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, express, mongoose

Suppose I have a very simple array like this `totalSpots = [95]` and it has only one value. Now a new booking is created and I want to automatically assign 1 parking-spot to the user whoever booked it and reduce array's value by 1 or whatever the user enter to make it `[94] or [95 - user_request_number]`

Below is the query to create a booking:

```
exports.createBooking = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await Auth.findOne({ _id: req.data.id });
    if (!user) return res.status(404).json({ error: "User not found" });

    const { parkingId, date, startTime } = req.body;
    
    const parking = await Parking.findOne({ _id: parkingId, date });

    if (!parking)
      return res.status(404).json({ error: "Parking details not available" });

    const bookingDetails = new Booking({
      user,
      parking,
      startTime,
      duration: req.body.duration,
      date: moment(req.body.date).format("MMM DD, YYYY"),
      endTime: req.body.endTime,
      paymentAmount: req.body.paymentAmount,
      isFeePaid: req.body.isFeePaid,
      status: "sent",
    });

    const save = await bookingDetails.save();

    return res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      msg: "Service Booked",
      data: { details: save },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
};
```

Currently I am not focusing on taking a spot values from users but I will do in the future.

And when a consumer removes his vehicle from that place, I want to increase a value as well, but not higher than the totalSpots that the merchant has set.

I am storing totalSpots as an array because in the future the value could be like this
`totalSpots = [1, 2, 3 ...upto 95]`

Comment: If you have an array as

let arr = [100]

you can modify it by doing

arr[0] = arr[0] + val.

or

arr[0]+=val

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for but it would be great of you to show this with the above code. I do not know how to get the last value after the booking is done and increase it when customer removes his car. I am kind of new to it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to rethink in your solution, if you save this information in an array, the information will be saved in the memory, if your server restarts, you are going to loose this info. You should control this in the database.
For example, suppose we have this merchant:

```
{ id: 1, name: "Merchant 1", capacity: 50 }
```

And we have this bookings:

```
{ id_merchant: 1, User: "Paul" }
{ id_merchant: 1, User: "John" }
{ id_merchant: 1, User: "mary" }
```

You subtract the merchant capacity (50) by the count of bookings it has (3), we have 47 free slots yet. And you add logic so what the sytem doesn't allow to book over the capacity

Comment: I think you are right. Can you please elaborate in detail?

Comment: Before adding a new booking you are going to use mongoose countDocuments() and compare with the capacity of the merchant, if the capacity is reached, you are not going to procede with the booking, you are going to return a message that the capacity is full.

Comment: In fact, I had the identical thought. We come into a problem where we don't know how much totalSpots has merchant posted if I update array on every single booking. Thank you for clarification.

Comment: Another issue that comes up is that since it is a time-based operation, how do I go about updating the available spots while a customer is leaving with their car and that place is empty now? I can not delete that data from the database and the comparison will not be handy in this situation.

Comment: Hmm I would do the following, before the user adds the parking slot to the cart, I would check if there is capacity, but I would not save or book anything right now. When the user are going to pay, I would check again if there is capacity, if it's over, message the user, if there is still capacity i would save to the database.